# fillRect not working when I have a lot of canvas elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas

I have a Vue app where I want to perform fillRect on 10000 canvas elements.
The code does work but it breaks when it has a big number sometimes.
What can I do about this?

```
for (let key = 1; key <= 10000; key++) {
    let card = document.getElementById(key);
    if (this.scratched.scratchedValue.includes(key) == false) {
        let cardCanvas = card.getContext('2d');
        cardCanvas.beginPath();
        cardCanvas.fillStyle = "#b6b6b4";
        cardCanvas.fillRect(0, 0, card.width, card.height);
        card.style.opacity = '1';
    } else {
        card.style.opacity = '1';
        card.style.outline = '2px solid #ef7200';
    }
}
```

[How it looks when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHO0.png)

[How it looks when it isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKME1.png)

Comment: Why do you have 10,000 elements on the page? Also, `key` is already a number, so `parseInt(key)` is useless. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have a 100 by 100 grid. The canvas elements are displayed in it.

Comment: Create one `<canvas>` of the full size and draw all the various rects on that single `<canvas>`.